# How to increase code coverage?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, code

My test class is passed but test coverage is 0%. Can any one help to increase tets coverage:

APex Class:

```
public class TopicOfInterestUserAsgmtDataAccessor implements TopicOfInterestUserAssignmentDAI {
    public List<Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c> getSubscribedTopicsOfInterestByUserId(Id userId) {
        return [
            SELECT Id, 
                User__c, 
                TopicofInterest__c 
            FROM Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c 
            WHERE User__c = :userId
        ];
    }

    public List<Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c> getSubscribedTopicsOfInterestLabelsByUserId(Id userId) {
        return [
            SELECT Id, 
                User__c, 
                toLabel(TopicofInterest__c) 
            FROM Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c 
            WHERE User__c = :userId
        ];
    }

    public void upsertUserTopicSelections(List<Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c> newOrExistingTopics) {
        upsert newOrExistingTopics; 
    }

    public void deleteUserTopicSelections(List<Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c> existingTopics) {
        delete existingTopics;
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
@IsTest
private class TopicOfInterestUserAsgmtDataAccessorTest {

    @testSetup
    private static void testSetup() {
    }

    @isTest
    Private static void testgetSubscribedTopicsOfInterestByUserId() {

        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email = 'standarduser@testorg.com',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', LastName = 'Testing', LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
                TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York', UserName = 'standarduser1@testorg.com');

        System.runAs(u) {

            Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c tci = new Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c();
            tci.User__c = u.Id;
            tci.TopicofInterest__c = 'Administrative';
            insert  tci;
            system.debug('**************tci'+tci);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not actually calling the class you want to test, just inserting a record. Is that class called from a trigger? Try directly calling the class instead of inserting records.

Answer (score 1):

I would make all your utility methods static:

```
public class TopicOfInterestUserAsgmtDataAccessor implements TopicOfInterestUserAssignmentDAI {
    public static List<Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c> getSubscribedTopicsOfInterestByUserId(Id userId) {
        return [
            SELECT Id, 
                User__c, 
                TopicofInterest__c 
            FROM Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c 
            WHERE User__c = :userId
        ];
    }

    public static List<Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c> getSubscribedTopicsOfInterestLabelsByUserId(Id userId) {
        return [
            SELECT Id, 
                User__c, 
                toLabel(TopicofInterest__c) 
            FROM Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c 
            WHERE User__c = :userId
        ];
    }

    public static void upsertUserTopicSelections(List<Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c> newOrExistingTopics) {
        upsert newOrExistingTopics; 
    }

    public static void deleteUserTopicSelections(List<Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c> existingTopics) {
        delete existingTopics;
    }

}
```

Your test class never calls anything from the class you're trying to test.

I also like to use static initialization code in my tests to organize the repetitive parts of the tests:

```
@IsTest
private class TopicOfInterestUserAsgmtDataAccessorTest {
    public static User testUser;
    public static List<Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c> toiuas;

    static {
        // This pattern prevents list has no rows errors when trying to
        // query for data created in the test, If using a pre-existing user
        // you don't need this pattern
        for (User u : [
            SELECT Id
            FROM User
            WHERE Alias = 'standt'
        ]) {
            testUser = u;
            break;
        }

        if (u != null) {
            toiuas = TopicOfInterestUserAsgmtDataAccessor.getSubscribedTopicsOfInterestByUserId(u.Id);
        }
    }

    @testSetup
    private static void testSetup() {
        Profile testUserProfile = [
            SELECT Id 
            FROM Profile 
            WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'
        ];

        testUser = new User(
            Alias = 'standt', 
            Email = 'standarduser@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LastName = 'Testing',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
            ProfileId = testUserProfile.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York', 
            UserName = 'standarduser1@testorg.com'
        );

        insert testUser;

        toiuas = new List<Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c>();

        for (Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            toiuas.add(new Topic_of_Interest_User_Assignment__c(
                // Populate required fields
                User__c = TestUser.id
            ));
        }

        insert toiuas;
    }

    @isTest
    Private static void deleteTest() {
        System.runAs(testUser) {
            TopicOfInterestUserAsgmtDataAccessor.deleteUserTopicSelections(toiuas);
        }
    }

    @isTest
    Private static void upsertTest() {
        System.runAs(testUser) {
            TopicOfInterestUserAsgmtDataAccessor.upsertUserTopicSelections(toiuas);
        }
    }

    @isTest
    Private static void get1Test() {
        System.runAs(testUser) {
            toiuas = TopicOfInterestUserAsgmtDataAccessor.getSubscribedTopicsOfInterestByUserId(UserInfo.getUserId());
            system.assert(!toiuas.isEmpty());
        }
    }

    @isTest
    Private static void get2Test() {
        System.runAs(testUser) {
            toiuas = TopicOfInterestUserAsgmtDataAccessor.getSubscribedTopicsOfInterestLabelsByUserId(UserInfo.getUserId());
            system.assert(!toiuas.isEmpty());
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add assert statements to check that your code actually works.